# Tool for automated SELinux policies generator for Docker containers in Openshift/Kubernetes clusters

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, openshift, selinux

I am looking for some tool that generates in an automated manner selinux policies for Docker containers in Openshift/Kubernetes clusters!

At the moment I am only aware of [Udica](https://github.com/containers/udica) and (kind of, a bit different) [gVisor](https://github.com/google/gvisor).

What are some other tools you would suggest me? Or maybe, how do I look for these kind of tools in the vast amount of repos and/or related scientific material?